# calculate percentage with subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to calculate a percentage in my SQL query.

This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT
DATE(processed_at) AS day,
(
  SELECT
  COUNT(*) FROM return_items
  WHERE return_id IN (SELECT id FROM returns WHERE DATE(processed_at) = day)
) as products_returned,
COUNT(*) as return_count,
(
  SELECT
  COUNT(*) as co_returns
  FROM returns
  WHERE return_method = 'mondial_relais'
  AND DATE(processed_at) = day
) as return_rate_mr
FROM returns
WHERE MONTH(processed_at) = 10
AND YEAR(processed_at) = 2011
GROUP BY day;
```

Basically I need the return_rate_mr to be a percentage value.
I tried doing something like `return_rate_mr * 100 / return_count as perc_value` but this  doesn't work. (I don't actually need the current `return_rate_mr` value, just the percentage.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Do you get an error or the wrong answer?

Comment: It's giving me `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'return_rate_mr' in 'field list'`

Comment: @Sled, shouldn't products returned be counting distinct product IDs? At the moment, it appears to be counting return IDs.

Comment: One return can have several return_items, and I need to count the total of them. Thanks for the heads up though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your original query returns the desired results, you can wrap it as a subquery:

```
SELECT
    day,
    return_rate_mr * 100 / return_count as perc_value,
    ... any other columns ...
FROM
    ( ... your original query here ...) as myalias;
```

Basically, the subquery creates a result set where the columns are renamed.  Then, the outer query is free to use those new column names.

Comment: Well, isn't that what you wanted?  OP said `(I don't actually need the current return_rate_mr value, just the percentage.`  However, if you want more columns, then just select them -- they're there.  Updated answer.

Comment: Yea sorry, I meant I didn't need the return_rate_mr, I still needed the rest. I didn't realize I should select them again in the main query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT
  `day`,
  `products_returned`,
  (`return_rate_mr` * 100) / `return_count` AS `percentage`
FROM (
  SELECT
  DATE(processed_at) AS day,
  (
    SELECT
    COUNT(*) FROM return_items
    WHERE return_id IN (SELECT id FROM returns WHERE DATE(processed_at) = day)
  ) as products_returned,
  COUNT(*) as return_count,
  (
    SELECT
    COUNT(*) as co_returns
    FROM returns
    WHERE return_method = 'mondial_relais'
    AND DATE(processed_at) = day
  ) as return_rate_mr
  FROM returns
  WHERE MONTH(processed_at) = 10
  AND YEAR(processed_at) = 2011
  GROUP BY day) AS `ss`
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
SELECT (`return_rate_mr` * 100 ) / `return_count` as "yourValue", OthersFields
 FROM SELECT
DATE(processed_at) AS day,
(
  SELECT
  COUNT(*) FROM return_items
  WHERE return_id IN (SELECT id FROM returns WHERE DATE(processed_at) = day)
) as products_returned,
COUNT(*) as return_count,
(
  SELECT
  COUNT(*) as co_returns
  FROM returns
  WHERE return_method = 'mondial_relais'
  AND DATE(processed_at) = day
) as return_rate_mr
FROM returns
WHERE MONTH(processed_at) = 10
AND YEAR(processed_at) = 2011
GROUP BY day;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DATE(processed_at) AS day,
       count(distinct id) as products_returned,
       COUNT(*) as return_count,
       100* sum(case return_method when 'mondial_relais' then 1 end) / COUNT(*) 
                as return_perc_mr
FROM returns
WHERE MONTH(processed_at) = 10
AND YEAR(processed_at) = 2011
GROUP BY day;
```

I suspect that products_returned should be counting distinct item_id values (or something similar), but this should duplicate the logic in the original query.